# How to test a Method with a Boolean return type in Java with JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, cobertura

I am writing a `JUnit` test case for a method to get a Line and Branch coverage. Method under test invokes another method of type `Boolean` and I am unable to cover that part because on the `Cobertura` report  the following line shows red.

```
if (getLoggingHandler().isGeneralDebugEnabled())
```

Method under test:

```
public void logMethodEndDebug(ILoggable l, String c, String m, String msg, Object... args) {

    if (getLoggingHandler().isGeneralDebugEnabled()) {
        String cf = ComponentUtils.createControlFrag(l, c);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cf);
        sb.append(m + StringConstants.SPACE + LogConstants.END);
        sb.append(StringConstants.BRACE_OPEN + String.format(msg, args) + StringConstants.BRACE_CLOSE);
        getLoggingHandler().handleGeneralDebug(sb.toString());
    }

}
```

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testLogMethodStartDebug() throws Exception {
    String var1 = "var1";
    String var2 = "var2";
    String var3 = "var3";
    Object[] object = new Object[] {"var4"}; 

    BaseComponent baseComponent = new BaseComponent();
    baseComponent.setLoggingHandler(new TestLoggingHandler());

    ILoggable loggable = new ServiceContext();

    baseComponent.logMethodEndDebug(loggable, var1, var2, var3, object);

    assertTrue(baseComponent.getLoggingHandler().isGeneralDebugEnabled());
}
```

Is there any way to cover this `getLoggingHandler().isGeneralDebugEnabled()`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a mock and then force the value to return true when `getLoggingHandler().isGeneralDebugEnabled()` is called

Here is what that would look like in code:

```
@Mock
private TestLoggingHandler mockLoggingHandler;

...

@Test
public void testLogMethodStartDebug() throws Exception {
    String var1 = "var1";
    String var2 = "var2";
    String var3 = "var3";
    Object[] object = new Object[] {"var4"}; 

    when(mockLoggingHandler.isGeneralDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(true);

    BaseComponent baseComponent = new BaseComponent();
    baseComponent.setLoggingHandler(mockLoggingHandler);

    ILoggable loggable = new ServiceContext();

    baseComponent.logMethodEndDebug(loggable, var1, var2, var3, object);

    assertTrue(baseComponent.getLoggingHandler().isGeneralDebugEnabled());
}
```

Alternately, if the setter for `generalDebugEnabled` is available you could do something like:

```
@Test
public void testLogMethodStartDebug() throws Exception {
    String var1 = "var1";
    String var2 = "var2";
    String var3 = "var3";
    Object[] object = new Object[] {"var4"}; 

    BaseComponent baseComponent = new BaseComponent();
    baseComponent.setLoggingHandler(new TestLoggingHandler());
    baseComponent.getLoggingHandler().setGeneralDebugEnabled(true);

    ILoggable loggable = new ServiceContext();

    baseComponent.logMethodEndDebug(loggable, var1, var2, var3, object);

    assertTrue(baseComponent.getLoggingHandler().isGeneralDebugEnabled());
}
```

Comment: You are awesome Blake. Mockito helped me and now it is covered. Thank you so much.